# Webpack-Nginx-Django - requests do not reach to the backend

Tags: django, docker, nginx, webpack

I have an application, where frontend is implemented with `Webpack`, `React` and the backend with `Python`, `Django`. I deployed it to a hosted server and used `nginx` as a reverse proxy. I use `Docker` for the deployment and I have 1 container for each (frontend, backend, nginx).
When I open the webpage of my app on a browser, it is correctly rendered. However, when I try to call any endpoint afterwards I get `HTTP 404 Not Found`. Logs for frontend and backend Docker containers are clean and `nginx` is having:

```
"POST /myendpoint/ HTTP/1.1" 404 146 "https://example.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/115.0"
```

*So I assume that the request cannot reach to the backend from nginx.*

I have tried different approaches of troubleshooting and solving (like playing around `nginx` config, `webpack` config, upgrading `webpack` version to 5), but no luck so far. **However**, when I deployed it to a local server of mine with Docker, but without `nginx`, it was working as expected, but through http (not https) of course.

My configs for nginx:

```
worker_processes 1;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    include mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;
    sendfile on;

    upstream backend {
        server 127.0.0.1:8000;
    }

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name example.com www.example.com;

        location /api {
            return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        }

        location / {
            return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        }
    }

    server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name example.com www.example.com;

        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;

        location /api {
            proxy_pass http://backend;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://frontend:3001;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }
    }
}
```

My configs for the webpack:

```
module.exports = merge(common, {
    mode: 'development',
    devServer: {
        historyApiFallback: true,
        contentBase: [path.join(__dirname, 'dist'), path.join(__dirname, 'public')],
        host: REACT_APP_HOST || '0.0.0.0',
        port: REACT_APP_PORT || 3001,
        public: 'example.com',
        allowedHosts: ['example.com', 'www.example.com'],
        disableHostCheck: true,
        headers: {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        }
    },
    devtool: 'source-map',
    module: {...}
})
```

Happy to provide more info or details if needed.

I am out of ideas now. Any help, suggestion, comment is much appreciated.
Thank you for your time!

Comment: Usually it happens when, Django is throwing error, but the error page itself missing, and error will subsequently throw 404. Can you share what is the response/error when u fire post request directly to backend on this url http://backend/myendpoint/

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried to POST on the server using `curl -X POST http://localhost:8000/myendpoint/ -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{some_data_here}'` and it returns the expected response. I can also see corresponding logs for Django.